# Can't get my old contacts

Tags: contacts, google-account

The screen on my old phone went black and I don't remember my Gmail name or password.  Store told me that I was S.O.L. concerning getting my info.  Is there anything I can do to get my info?

Comment: Can you still connect the phone to a computer via USB and view the data stored on it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what details you gave on your Google account. You have to had entered either a recovery email or you phone number and your real name. If you had these, you can try to recover your username from https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/forgotusername and after that you can reset your password from https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/ .